# AJAX JSON Request to MVC IIS Syntax Error

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I have a MVC4 project that works well inside of visual studio 2010, but when I deploy it to IIS, I am getting textstatus of "parsererror", and errorThrown of "syntaxError" (which land in the ajax error method). Any ideas why? I am using IE8 (in browser mode IE8, and document mode IE8 standards), but I have included json3.js just incase.. I have added $.support.cors = true and even tried crossDomain=true, but nothing seems to get it work in IIS, any suggestions? Here is the code:

```
JSON_AjaxRequest: function (controller, method, parameters, callBackSuccess) {

    parameters = JSON.stringify(parameters);

    var hasError = false;
    var lastErrorMessage = "";

    $.support.cors = true;

    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "http://myServer/myApplication/" + controller + "/" + method,
        data: parameters,
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            callBackSuccess(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            hasError = true;
            lastErrorMessage = errorThrown;
        },
        complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {

            if (hasError) {
                var errorObject = MyBuildErrorMsgRoutine(lastErrorMessage);
                MyDisplayErrorMsgRoutine(errorObject);
            }
        },
        dataType: 'json'
});
```

Comment: if you inspect the object `jqXHR` you maigh get more details about the problem. You mentioned on your question but are you really using cross domain requests?

Comment: Why do you use cross domain requests? Wouldn't it be easier to use an url like '"/"+controller+"/"+method' ?

Comment: @Claudio there are no issues reported in this case, in jqXHR

Comment: @ITFarmer I suppose you are right, I dont need the crossdomain request, I was just listed things that I have tried to get this to work.

Comment: @ITFarmer thanks for getting me on the right track! Solved.. To get it to work I changed the url to "/SiteName/ControllerName/MethodName"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved thanks to ITFarmer putting me on track.

For inside VS2010 use:

```
 url: "http://localhost:<port>/" + controller + "/" + method,
```

For IIS use:

```
 url: "/SiteName/ControllerName/MethodName"
```

edit: note the 'SiteName' I mention here, is actually the application name in IIS, so looking at the IIS tree you see Sites, then under that 'Default' (or something else), then under that is your list of application names, which I called SiteName above.